# How to create an asynchronous Gulp plugin?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, gulp

Here is my code:

```js
const through = require('through2');

function gulpPlugin() {
    let filesCount = 0;

    function transform(file, encoding, callback) {
        if (file.stat.isDirectory())
            return callback();

        Promise.all([promise1(file), promise2(file)]).then(function(values) {
            if (values[0] === values[1]) {
                this.push(file);
                ++filesCount;
            }
            callback();
        });
    }

    function flush(callback) {
        console.log('files:', filesCount);
        callback();
    }

    return through.obj(transform, flush);
}
```

Having the `callback` parameter implies that the `transform()` may run asynchronously, however this does not work, so no file gets passed through the plugin.

Documentation on the underlying [stream.Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback) claims that "transform() - should do whatever has to be done in this specific Transform class... do **asynchronous** I/O, process things, and so on... callback - call this function when you are done processing the supplied chunk".

Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, the context in the promise callback has changed, so the correct code should be:

```js
const that = this;

Promise.all([promise1(file), promise2(file)]).then(function(values) {
    ...
    that.push(file);
});
```